# NodeJS - Request Elevated Privileges (WIN/OSX)

Tags: windows, node.js, macos

I'm currently a small terminal based application in NodeJS and compiling with [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/). My application is going to require elevated privileges on both Windows and OSX in order to work, how can I accomplish this with Node? I haven't been able to find anything that gave me a start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows there's `node-windows` package that offers UAC control.

In OS X the standard way for command-line tools is **not** to ask for permissions. Tools only use permissions they're given (sometimes implicitly via the dangerous setuid flag), and if that's not enough, they fail and ask be run with `sudo`.

If your tool only needs to permissions briefly (e.g. to open a port or a secret file), then you can require it to be started with `sudo` and then drop privileges using `process.setuid`/`setgid`.